# Snap scroll only one section (Fullpage.js or similar)

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm trying to create full sized header section that would snap to next section automatically when scrolled and then the snapscrolling would be killed and switched to normal scrolling.

```
<header class="fullheight fullwidth">
full image background snap to main on scroll
</header>
<main class="normalscroll longcontent">
normal content sections
</main>
```

I've tried following plugins FSVS, fullPage.js, onepage-scroll but i haven't had any success with creating only one section. They all seem to rely on several following sections. Many thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: You can take a look at this tutorial, although its not working perfectly for phones: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/04/09/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/ The latest section does what you are looking for.

Comment: OMG @Alvaro this is perfect! .pp-scrollable works perfect for the cause

Comment: Except the page jumps randomly depending on the scroll speed... Is there a method to disable normal scroll before the effect and sliding to the main content?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Im basically trying to freeze scrolling meanwhile animating. My problem is that I start with fullscreen block and then jump to scrollable content.. and now user ends up pretty randomly to different parts of scrollable depending on the speed of scrolling... I basically only need intro screen with pagepiling then I can kill it. I'm not actually sure is fixed layers the best option here... Since i basically only want to jump from fullscreen intro to normal content.

Answer (score 0):

try to read this first

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/614

it called normal scrolling after one section

well this more information that would help...

if you are using FullPage.js and you want to stop it after the first section,
u need this `autoScrolling: false` for that section. because if u downloaded the FullPage.js the default is `autoScrolling: true`

example:

section 1 `autoScrolling: true`

section 2 `autoScrolling: false`

section 3 `autoScrolling: false`

Comment: can you please add some more information, so that the answer will stay valid even if then link breaks? thanks!

Comment: edited, but i'm not quite sure to answer this question. because it's still issues category in the forums.. many people looking for this too